# how to run hp uft script in multiple machines at a time?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Presently i have prepared framework script in my system but ,now i want to run the script in multiple machines where only it will display browser execution,means once i start the test it will automatically start executing in multiple systems with provided test data from excel.

Please provide any script or solution ,how to execute this type of script.

My Script Is:

```
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("name:=userVO.userName").Set "Uname"
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("name:=userVO.userPasscode").Set "password"
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebButton("name:=Login").Click
```

Comment: Please provide some more clarity on this - do you want to trigger the test from one particular machine ? and the test should start on other machines  ?. i am not sure what exactly you need but you need to have UFT installed on all the systems that you need to run for

Comment: You'd be better off setting up ALM or Jenkins to trigger the test across multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, you cannot control QTP on remote machines.
However, if you use AOM, you can create a vbs that can simultaneously get triggered at a specific event. Like the clock hit 10:00 PM everyday

```
Do While(cStr(Time) <> "22:00:00")
   Wscript.Sleep = 1000
Loop

            Set objQTP = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

            If objQTP.Launched Then 'optional step to restart QTP
                            objQTP.Test.Save
                            objQTP.Quit
            End If
            objQTP.Launch
            objQTP.Open "Testpath",True,True
            objQTP.Test.Run
            While objQTP.Test.isRunning
               Wscript.Sleep 1000
            Wend
            objQTP.Quit
            set objQTP = Nothing
```

Save it as vbs and make sure to run it  by double clicking on all the machines.

P.S. I myself have not run this script. Kindly validate the script before using. Also, change the code according to time settings on those machines.

If the above one is not feasible, you can use ALM to run your tests.